# Suspending leads to black screen

Tags: nvidia, suspend

I started using Ubuntu 2 days ago, I am completely fresh with Linux, and I am facing some problems
but the worst of them is that, when I leave the laptop for a while or try to suspend it manually, the PC is frozen and a black screen appears, and I have to force a hard shutdown and reboot every time the OS sleeps.
I searched for a solution, and found that it may be related with Nvidia-drivers, but I don't know, how to setup them correctly.
PS: Nothing appears in Additional Drivers section in Software & Updates.

Specs:
Asus A17
R7 5800h
RTX3060

Comment: Inspect the logs for clues of what exactly is causing the problem, perhaps start with the system log in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Additional Drivers page does not see my graphics card 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007886/additional-drivers-page-does-not-see-my-graphics-card-16-04)

Comment: Check This, I followed the instruction and it worked for me.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved as following.
I uninstalled all Nvidia-related drivers that came pre-installed with the system and then reinstalled them cleanly. As a result of these actions, the problem has been successfully resolved and the system is now functioning properly.
this article can be useful
https://askubuntu.com/a/1150059/1723327

thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

My laptop would do the same. I know if you have the computer in suspension mode and when you come back to the computer to unsuspend your session, in other words wake the computer to st art your session again the laptop will in some cases(like my laptop would do) wake up for a second and then go right back to a blank screen. As soon as you see that blank screen just give it a few seconds and then after those few seconds click down the touch pad. And if that didn't do it right away click one of the letter key(s) from the keyboard. And still if that doesn't still work, close the lid of the laptop. Leave the lid shut for about 10-20 seconds, then do the process over again  with click of the cursor or one of the letter keys from the keyboard.